# How do I pass a parameter to an mvc ActionResult using Jquery Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an id parameter back to MVC action result using Jquery Ajax. I want to execute a StoredProcedure which is expecting the id as a parameter.

I have tried various methods to pass the id back to the ActionResult but I keep failing and getting different errors.

Can somebody please assist and show me what I'm doing wrong.

```js
function UpdateUsingId(Id) {
  $('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var Id = $(this).find('td').first().text().trim();
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("CreateNewRecord", "Sales")',
      data: Id,
      success: function(data) {
        alert("succes");
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        cache: true;
      }
    })
  })
}
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateNewRecord(int? Id) 
{
  var data = db.SP_GetIdForUpdate_Insert(Id);
  return View(data);
}
```

Comment: Your AJAX URL mentioned `SaveData` action but you're only included `CreateNewRecord` action. Please include the action method you want to pass the parameter.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Oh apologies for that, I included the wrong ActionResult. I've edited and put the correct Actionresult.

Comment: @ZUKISABHOLOSHA please make sure you have the right route in your route config file and the parameter your are passing is `Id` too . and update your ajax data as  `data: {"Id":Id},`

Comment: @Haroonnasir I'm not sure why my function is hitting the Ajax, I'm getting a "404 Not Found" error. I also get a "XHR failed loading: GET"......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a parameter by this way

```
  function UpdateUsingId(Id) {
  $('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var Id = $(this).find('td').first().text().trim();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("SaveData", "Sales")',
      data: {"Id":Id},
      success: function(data) {
        alert("succes");
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        cache: true;
      }
    })
  })
}
```

You have to pass data in Json format like this :  {"Id":Id}
and pass it in a save data action in sales controller

Comment: This is giving me a 404 not found, and I also get a "XHR failed loading: GET"

Comment: You should add `type: "POST",` in ajax 
I have edited my answer.
And please check action name should be same  in controller and in ajax url

Comment: @ZUKISABHOLOSHA wc